# Embed Calendly Script in NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, widget, calendly

I am [trying to embed calendly](https://help.calendly.com/hc/en-us/articles/223147027-Embed-options-overview?tab=advanced#4) in my nextjs project.

Not sure however how to go about it. Ideally, I just embed it on a single page (and not in `_app` or `_document`)

This is what I've got so far:

```
import Script from 'next/script';
import React from 'react';

const Page = () => {
    Calendly.initInlineWidget({
        url: 'https://calendly.com/mycalendlyaccount/30min?month=2022-05'
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <Script src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js" />

            <div
                className="calendly-inline-widget"
                style="min-width:320px;height:580px;"
                data-auto-load="false"></div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Page;
```

This obviously doesn't work. I don't really know where to put:

```
    Calendly.initInlineWidget({
        url: 'https://calendly.com/mycalendlyaccount/30min?month=2022-05'
    });
```

I find their [example on their website I linked to above](https://help.calendly.com/hc/en-us/articles/223147027-Embed-options-overview?tab=advanced#4) pretty unhelpful in this regard. Could somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 6):

Quickly tried this one and it seems to be working just fine, adapt as needed:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
```

```
[...]
  useEffect(() => {
    window.Calendly.initInlineWidget({
      url: 'https://calendly.com/my-calendar/30min?month=2022-05',
      parentElement: document.getElementById('calendly-inline-widget')
    });
  }, [])
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <script src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js"></script>
      </Head>
      <>
          <div
            id="calendly-inline-widget"
            style={{minWidth: 320, height: 580}}
            data-auto-load="false"
          >
          </div>
      </>
[...]
```

Comment: You can also use the react-calendly npm package to make the embed code less verbose https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendly

Comment: how do you import Calendly? where is window.Calendly coming from?

Comment: the Calendly prop is set on the window when the script runs that is linked to with the script tag <script src="https://assets.calendly.com/.....

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach to using `Calendly.initPopupWidget` in a single component within a NextJS app. Note, the app is running Next version 12.

This solution uses Next's `Script` component to embed the third-party Calendly script.

```
import Script from 'next/script';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function CalendlyButton() {
  function handleClick() {
    // @ts-ignore
    window.Calendly.initPopupWidget({
      url: 'https://calendly.com/foo/bar',
    });
    return false;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Script
        src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js"
        type="text/javascript"
        async
      />
      <link
        href="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
      />

      <button onClick={handleClick}>Schedule</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Upon further thought I am strongly considering using the [react-calendly](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendly) dependency given the number of third-party scripts Calendly injects with this approach.